# Number of Fed Rate hikes prices in

Tags: interest-rates, quant-trading-strategies, fed, fed-funds

Could someone please explain to me how the calculation of the market expected FED rate hikes is done?

Thank you.[image]

Comment: It's a bit of a misnomer. The market expects (tutorial here https://www.cmegroup.com/education/demos-and-tutorials/fed-funds-futures-probability-tree-calculator.html ) the rates to go up, let's say, 125 basis points. Assuming that the fed changes the rates by 25 basis points at a time, thats would be "5 hikes". But it could be 1 hike of 50 bps at a time, and 3 hikes of 25. Also nothing is stopping the fed from hiking e.g. 30 bps, or some other non-traditional amount, although that would be very weird and unusual; or from changing the rate not at a regularly scheduled meeting.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and tutorial!

Comment: @DimitriVulis so in short, they look at futures of FF to estimate the probabilities. I guess futures are traded only for up to a certain months. For beyond that, they can use fwd OIS swap rates, right? using which they can estimate mkt expectations of FF rate 2/3 yrs down the line as well

Comment: @qwerty_uiop, strictly speaking that data in the screenshot is from Bloomberg's own tool, called WIRP, where you can select whether you want to use futures or OIS. The general idea is the same though. Long run, like 3 years is not really feasible though. For example, the FED does not even have the dates for the FOMC meetings released yet.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments above.
I'm currently trying to understand the number of 25bps-equivalent rake hikes that the ECB will do in 2022.
How is this done?
Do I look at the theoretical rate of an OIS, from today to the end of the year? Or from today to the 15-Dec meeting?
Or is there another instrument I should be looking at?
Thank you.